# How to setup Entity, Form and TWIG concerning numbers with decimals

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony 4 and have setup an entity with a field like this:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2))
*/
private $rueckmenge;
```

In my form it is defined like this:

```
->add('rueckmenge', NumberType::class,
                array('label' => $this->rueckmenge_label,
                      'disabled' => false,
                      'html5' => true,
                      'scale' => 2,
                      'rounding_mode' => NumberToLocalizedStringTransformer::ROUND_HALF_EVEN,
                      'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control',
                                      'placeholder' => $this->rueckmenge_label,
                                      'title' => $this->rueckmenge_title,
                                      'min'  => 0,
                                      'max'  => 9999.99,
                                      'step' => 0.01,),
                ))
```

If I enter in my form a value like 7.5 or 7,5 and debug the controller mathod $form->getData() it returns always an integer valued "7":

[image]

And this is stored on the database.

Comment: if the locales get mixed up, this would explain everything, can you take a look into the actually sent data (i.e. browser request, dev mode, network tab, find the POST request, check the contents) and look up the locale set in symfony/php.

Comment: The locale is 'de' as you can see in the debug:

Comment: sorry, the debug picture has cut it off, but its 'de'. The locale may be switched by the user, cause the application I build is multilingual (at the moment its 'de' and 'en')

Comment: What is the value of the param in the POST request? You can view that with the browser debugger

Comment: Here the value is always with point: "7.5" even if I entered "7,5"

Comment: that's probably due to the input type being "number" which should delocalize it (so to speak) but the NumberType should handle this. I don't know why you have this error tbh. Maybe you need to clear the cache (which would be stupid, as you're obviously working on dev)

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: When I created the entity with make:entity symfony created getter and setter method and here the type was set to int. I changed that to float and now its working.